# VS 2010 Error when creating or opening projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed new copy of visual studio 2010 and when i tried to open old project i got error message.

[image]

So i just tried to create new project, and received the same message.

No valid exports were found that match the contraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==     "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBufferFactoryService") AndAlso     (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentiy") AndAlso "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBufferFactoryService".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))', invalid exports may have been rejected.

I already tried to remove and re-install it. After that did not work i tried to use repair option.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit OS.

Comment: Try uninstall, then reinstall. If that fails, you are in the same boat as me, need to do OS reinstall.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/600234/cannot-create-or-open-any-project-in-vs2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. After a suggestion from a coworker I installed VS2010 SP1. After SP1 was installed issue has not come back.

Comment: It's not specific to version. It also reproduces on VS 2012. The problem is the visual studio cache file. Of course reinstalling VS clears that cache file but its not required to do all that. See the answer above.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar error with Visual Studio 2012 that seemed to have been caused when I enabled ClearType text on a different monitor. I found a solution in another MSDN thread:

Remove the file: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache

in the folder: in C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

After starting VS2012 re-generates the file and everything works.

Comment: Solved for Visual Studio 2013